# In group theory, if G is a group, what does the notation G' mean?

Tags: group-theory

I am currently working my way through Daniel Gorenstein's Book "Finite Groups", learning about transfer and the focal subgroup and the notation G' keeps popping up and I can't seem to figure out what it refers to. I will give you an example of where it's used:
If G possesses a proper normal subgroup K such that G(with a bar on top) = G/K is a p-group, then G(with a bar on top)' is a subset of G(with a bar on top)

Comment: $G'=[G,G]$ is the [commutator subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup).

Comment: It is defined in the "Notation and Terminology" section of the book at the beginning of Chapter 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commutator group, $G'=[G,G]=\langle aba^{-1}b^{-1}: a,b\in G\rangle$.

Note that is a normal subgroup of $G$, and $G'$ represent how commutative is the group, ie $G$ is abelian iff $G'=\{1\}$.

Comment: Your definition needs to use $\langle$ and $\rangle$ instead of $\{$ and $.\}$

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft yes, I fixed. Thanks